# How to set onClick event on angular-calendar?

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar

I want to use a calendar module for my angular project.  So far I have found this one: https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar

My angular website shows the calendar but I don't know how to set **onClick** events.  I have simply inserted this code in my **component.html** file:

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view
  [viewDate]="viewDate"
  [events]="events">
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

How could I set an onClick event, which is called when the user clicks on a day?

Comment: The repo has a link to some documentation. You should start there.

Comment: You can find the solution to your problem by reading through the documentation (follow the links from the github repo page).

Comment: It would be good if someone could answer this question. Unfortunately the people involved with the angular-calendar reused (poorly) the term "event".

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular-Calender. You can use the `eventClicked` event binding to handle that.

On component.html:

```
<mwl-calendar-month-view
  [viewDate]="viewDate"
  [events]="events">
  (eventClicked)="eventClicked($event)"
</mwl-calendar-month-view>
```

On component.ts

```
import { CalendarEvent } from 'angular-calendar';

.
.
eventClicked({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void {
  console.log( event);
}
```

[Documentation](https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/clickable-events)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the dayClicked listener

(dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"

```
  <mwl-calendar-month-view
    *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh"
    [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
    (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
    (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
    (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
  >
```

> ```
> dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
>     console.log("dayClicked", date, events );
> }
> ```